# I need some css to fix a mobile responsiveness of my wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, responsive-design

my site is http://psychicrx.com/ it seems normal till i get down to mobile view been looking around for a solution and not sure what to do It gives me a full screens worth of white space when i check it on mobile and have to scroll down to see the site content please help i am getting frustrated that i cant find this in the css and i dont know maybe there is a good plugin that would edit the code for me that is causing this issue thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a standard theme delivered with Worpress (like twentyfifteen) and extend it by doing a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Answer (score 0):

Your #mobile-navigation, #mobile-navigation-jquery goes to display:block when in mobile mode.

Change this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 620px)
#mobile-navigation, #mobile-navigation-jquery {
display: block;
}
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 620px)
#mobile-navigation, #mobile-navigation-jquery {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: ok this sounds like what i need to do where do i find the file in wordpress dashboard

Comment: I have no idea, try "find in files" with Notepad++ in the root folder on your server?

Answer (score 0):

The nav is occupying that space. You have to make it have no width when it gets to mobile.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .
  .
  .
  width: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a little css with #mobile-navigation-jquery i just put it to width 0 and it works fine now also i used a plugin that worked real well without me having to edit the themes css thanks